# Firebase authentication taking too long to create user in cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

currently I'm having a problem where calling the auth#createUser method takes up to 10 seconds to proceed to call it's `Promise#then` method. I'm getting these timestamps from the firebase & google cloud function logger. I feel that I may be doing something wrong, although I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Before you say to contact the firebase support, I already have and they told me to come here.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let database = admin.firestore();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, response) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(response);

    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: data.email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: data.password,
        displayName: data.name,
        disabled: false,
    }).then(user => {
        database.collection('users').doc(data.username).set({
            uid: user.uid,
            email: data.email,
            name: data.name,
            username: data.username
        }).catch(error => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error)
        });
        console.log('The entire thing is done successfully!');
        return {
            response: user
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error);
    });
    console.log('Found my way to the end of the method');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not dealing with promises correctly.  onCall functions should return a promise that resolves with the data that you want to return to the client.  Right now, your function is returning nothing.  The return statement inside the `then` callback isn't actually sending anything to the client.  What you will need to do instead is return the promise chain:

```
return admin.auth().createUser(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

Note the return in front of all that.

Also, you will need to handle the promise returned by `set()`.  Just calling `catch` isn't sufficient.  You will need to return that promise as well from the `then` callback.

I strongly suggest learning how promises work in JavaScript - without proper handling, your functions will simply not work correct, and often behave in confusing ways.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not that familiar with nodejs. I'm more of a compiled language type of person.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with whether or not the language is compiled.  This is how you do asynchronous programming in JavaScript.  Async programming always requires special care no matter the language.